# What "Squalor" Esmé means

Tags: word-choice, word-request, literature

In ["For Esmé - with Love and Squalor"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Esm%C3%A9%E2%80%94with_Love_and_Squalor), Esme seems to use "squalor" without knowing what the word means. Assuming she mistakes it for another word, what would the other word be?
Good answers provide contextually appropriate words, which are written or spoken similarly to "squalor" (maybe "splendor") or convince that "squalor" is what she really means. Links to articles or online resources are more than welcome.

(This question started as English tutoring exercise, so I am posting it here.)

Answer (score 1):

This gets convoluted. J.D. Salinger had a collection of short stories named *Nine Stories* in which one of stories was ["For Esmé—with Love and Squalor."](http://sittingbee.com/for-esme-with-love-and-squalor-j-d-salinger/) So presumably there was some other work which analyzed that story and ended up with the title "For Esmé with Love and Squalor Analysis."

The short story is written as if it is from a Sargent X who suffered from Posttraumatic Stress Disorder (PTSD).  Esmé is evidently a young teenage girl the Sargent meet.

"With Love and Squalor" is certainly and odd phrase, most likely to be dramatic than factual. "With love" has the standard because of personal feelings, but the squalor use is odd. The use would seem to indicate that the writer is in a very bad mental state.

Comment: Ahh, my bad! I am asking about the short story, and this "Analysis" was just pasted by mistake. I am editing the question.